# Custom control setting image source from downloaded stream

Tags: windows-phone-8

My application shows images that require an Authorization http header to be downloaded. I am thus creating a custom control `AuthenticatedImage` that creates an HttpClient with necessary headers, downloads the image stream and sets the control template's `Image` control source.

I am doing something wrong with threading it seems as I get this exception when calling `bitmapImage.SetSource(stream)`:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Additional information: Read is not supported on the main thread when buffering is disabled.
```

These are the simplified relevant methods of my custom control:

```
public override async void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    this.image = GetTemplateChild(imagePartName) as Image;

    await this.SetSource(this.Source);
}

private async Task SetSource(Uri uri)
{
    var stream = await DownloadImage(uri);

    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    this.image.Source = bitmapImage;
}

private Task<Stream> DownloadImage(Uri uri)
{
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(/* custom header */);

    return httpClient.GetStreamAsync(uri);
}
```

I'm looking for the proper way of doing this.

Comment: Are you using post method ??

Comment: No... I am downloading an image & using GetStreamAsync as you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using GetAsync with a specific HttpCompletionOption instead of GetStreamAsync.

`httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);`

The same problem happened if I used `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeaderRead`, so I assume it has to do with the response not being completely available by the time the task returns, and that it is the behavior of GetStreamAsync.

Answer (score 0):

add fllow code :

> Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {  #Set Image Source Operator with  your code # });

cross thread operator exception.

Comment: I am getting the same exception by wrapping my `bitmapImage.SetSource(stream)` line in what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach. I used this many times, may this will help you.

```
private Task<Stream> DownloadImage(string uri)
    {
      HttpWebRequest imageRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
    imageRequest.Headers["Your Header key"] = header value;
    imageRequest.BeginGetResponse(Imageresponse, imageRequest);

    }


     private void Imageresponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            data.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                            memoryStream.Position = 0;
                            byte[] buffer = null;
                            if (memoryStream != null && memoryStream.Length > 0)
                            {
                                BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
                                buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)memoryStream.Length);
                                Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                {
                                    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };
                                    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
                                    this.image.Source = bitmapImage;
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionHelper.WriteLog(ex);
                }

            }
```